# Clipboard syncronization between wine and X11

Tags: wine, clipboard

I installed Lingoes dictionary in Wine. It has a popup translator that is triggered by clipboard change. When I copy or select an item it must translate the word, but in Wine, when I copy or select a word, Lingoes dictionary remains unresponsive as if nothing has been copied.  I can paste into Lingoes dictionary through right click context menu then it translates.

How can I enable auto clipboard sync between Wine and X11?

Comment: What version of ubuntu and wine are you using(use `wine --version`)?

Comment: @Jobin I have Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit, I also upgraded to GTK 3.10 using gnome3 ppa. Wine version `wine-1.7.15` I also want to apply clipboard sync to other playonlinux prefixes.

Comment: FWIW wine's clipboard integrates automatically for me with KDE.

Comment: @Sparhawk
Thank you for the info. Then it appears to be desktop environment issue. It must not be that hard to apply it to GNU Ubuntu

Comment: It might also be something else that differs in our system. I seem to remember it working with Unity ages ago. Just so we can minimise differences, can you try the clipboard in notepad?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is listed in [this thread](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2012-July/331120.html), namely you need to create registry entry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver]
"UsePrimarySelection"="1"
```

(some sources suggest `"UsePrimarySelection"="y"` but that has the same effect).

For more information refer [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/901970/using-clipboard-with-xfce-and-tightvnc). In particular if you want to copy text from VNC server (e.g. Linux) to VNC client (e.g. Windows), you need to install additionally [`autocutsel`](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) and add to `~/.vnc/xstartup` something like this:

```
autocutsel -s PRIMARY -fork
```

This is needed because historically [VNC protocol uses old and deprecated CUTBUFFER](https://archive.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2003-February/037299.html) (legendary applications like `xterm` support it from those ancient times out of the box), while new applications like Wine use CLIPBOARD by default (switched to PRIMARY with registry option above). `autocutsel` should be used to synchronize all these types of buffers.

Answer (score 2):

*Thanks to [dma_ks answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/913231/258256) I found a variant that worked for me.*

1. Open a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. `export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32/` *use your defined WINEPREFIX*
3. *(optional)* `export WINEDEBUG=fixme-all`
4. *(optional)* Query if you have it already set

```
:~$ wine reg query "HKLM\Software\Wine\X11 Driver"
reg: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
:~$ wine reg query "HKCU\Software\Wine\X11 Driver"
reg: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
```

5. ADD the registry key to Current User (HKCU) and Local Machine (HKLM), *what I have read in the source code doesn't seem to check HKLM but I could have missed it somewhere, probably doesn't hurt to have them both set.*

```
:~$ wine reg add "HKCU\Software\Wine\X11 Driver" /v UsePrimarySelection /t REG_SZ /d 1
The operation completed successfully
:~$ wine reg add "HKLM\Software\Wine\X11 Driver" /v UsePrimarySelection /t REG_SZ /d 1
The operation completed successfully
```

*In the example I have set it to `1` which defines* **TRUE**. *Other valid options, as defined in the [source files](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/winex11.drv/x11drv_main.c#l121), are*

- TRUE : `y Y t T 1`
- FALSE : `n N f F 0`

6. You can now close the terminal window and start your wine app

*Note1: `WINEPREFIX` must be set to and coincide with the wineprefix on which your application runs, if each app runs on a different prefix you will probably need to modify each one*

*Note2: HKLM and HKCU are registry key shortcuts for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER respectively*

*Note3: You can perform all of this aswell by using the GUI app regedit. You can launch it with `wine regedit`.*

**Details:**

Having a look through the [source code](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/winex11.drv/x11drv_main.c#l349) it appears as wine

1. First checks the application specific value `HKCU\Software\Wine\AppDefaults\app.exe\X11 Driver\UsePrimarySelection` and returns its assigned value if it exists
2. if it did not find an application specific value it checks the current user "general" value `HKCU\Software\Wine\X11 Driver\UsePrimarySelection` and returns its assigned value if it exists

Related:

- [Bug 31216 in WineHQ](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31216)
- [Bug 47344 in WineHQ](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47344)
- [Bug 50598 in WineHQ](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50598)
- [WineHq Forums discussion on Copy/Paste](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=8334)
- [CMDLine Windows Registry Edit Article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this!